# Retrieve the list of Form fields in Google.Apis libraries

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google.Apis set of libraries for Google integration and I wonder: is there a way to retrieve all fields that are contained in specific Google Form document assuming I have its Id and properly authorized